# Pull data from child tags referring to class name or ID of parent tag

Tags: vba, excel

I need to pull the message "message i've to retry" from below HTML tags

```
<div id="m_7qo0yziAwqKk02Gud0IM" style="padding: 0px 0px 10px; width: 681px;" class="w-7qo0yziAwqKk02Gud0t9 moduleContent">
 <div id="ext-comp-1345" class=" x-panel" style="width: 681px;">
 <div class="x-panel-bwrap" id="ext-gen931">
 <div class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader x-column-layout-ct" id="ext-gen932" style="width: 681px;">
 <div class="x-column-inner" id="ext-gen934" style="width: 681px;">
 <div id="ext-comp-1346" class=" x-panel diff-area diff-enabled x-column" style="font-size: 23px; width: 591px;">
 <div class="x-panel-bwrap" id="ext-gen936">
 <div class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader" id="ext-gen937" style="width: 591px;">message i've to retry</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="ext-comp-1348" class=" x-panel x-column" style="padding: 4px 0px 4px 2px; font-size: 11px; color: rgb(160, 160, 160); width: 589px;">
</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I'm using below VBA code to point till parent tag, but don't know how to point child tag to fetch the data.

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = IE.document
IE.navigate "Site link"
Dim dd As Variant
dd = doc.getElementById("m_7qo0yziAwqKk02Gud0IM")
```

Could anyone lead me

Thanks !

Comment: Once you have `dd` set as a reference the parent div, the next enclosed div can be referenced using `dd.firstChild`, so just add on `.firstChild` until you reach the div you want, then grab its `.innerHTML` (or `.innerText`) property. BTW, you need to use `Set` when assigning an object value to a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tim. 
Could you please add a sample code, just to start with

Comment: I tried like this          
`Dim sdd as variant
sdd = dd.Child.doc.getElementByClassName("x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader").innerText`
Would have been good if worked, because it is direct call for object.

Comment: What are `Child` and `doc`, and what happened when you tried that? `getElement**s**ByClassName` returns a collection, so you need to reference the first member of the collection in order to read any of its properties. Plenty of examples on google.

Comment: Well, still trying to figure out via google !

Comment: If you update your question with current code that might get you more specific suggestions.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Could you please evaluate my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used below code to get the data,

```
Dim finalout As Variant
Dim dd As HTMLObjectElement    
Set dd = doc.getElementById("m_7qo0yziAwqKk02Gud0IM") 'assign web elements to a HTML document object
finalout = dd.getElementsByClassName(" x-panel x-column")(2).innerText  'now we have a bunch of required webtags in dd, out of which get your data by using methods and proper syntax
MsgBox finalout
```

It worked for me.
:-)

Comment: Looks like you figured it out!  Don't forget to accept your own answer.

Comment: Yes, gone thro' VBA documents.
Regarding "accept the answer", it doesn't allow me till tomorrow !